# Unresolved overloaded function type when rewriting code c++

Tags: c++, mesh

I'm using ESP8266WiFiMesh library in my project which I run on nodeMCU. When the example provided by the library is in the Ardunino ino file it works well, but when I rewrite it into c++ cpp h files I run into some problems. In the Mesh::Mesh when I create an instance of ESP8266WiFiMesh class I provide two parameters: chipId and callback.

Error that I get when providing callback function (manageRequest)

```
<unresolved overloaded function type> to std::function<String(String)>
```

I'm struggling for a few days and I couldn't find any solution.

Here's the original example code that I use.
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFiMesh/examples/HelloMesh/HelloMesh.ino

Mesh.cpp :

```
#include "Mesh.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMesh.h>

unsigned int request_i = 0;
unsigned int response_i = 0;

Mesh::Mesh() {
    /* Create the mesh node object */
    /* Here I'm getting Unresolved overloaded function when providing manageRequest function (callback) */
    ESP8266WiFiMesh mesh_node = ESP8266WiFiMesh(ESP.getChipId(), manageRequest);

    /* Create the utils node object */
    utilsy = new Utils();

#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Setting up mesh node...");
#endif

    /* Initialize the mesh node */
    mesh_node.begin();
}

/**
* Callback for when other nodes send you data
*
* @request The string received from another node in the mesh
* @response The string to send back to the other node
*/
String Mesh::manageRequest(String request) {

    /* Split request */
    String requestedTo = utilsy->getDelimitedValues(request, '.', 0);
    String requestedFrom = utilsy->getDelimitedValues(request, '.', 1);
    const char *cstr = requestedFrom.c_str();
    String requestedMessage = utilsy->getDelimitedValues(request, '.', 2);
    String requestedState = utilsy->getDelimitedValues(request, '.', 3);

#ifdef DEBUG
    /* Print out received message */
    Serial.print("Requested from: " + requestedFrom);
    Serial.print("\tMessage: " + requestedMessage);
    Serial.println("\tRequested state: " + requestedState);
#endif

    /* return a string to send back */
    char response[60];
    //TODO should send back with same message and giving proper state [0,1] whether LED turned on/off
    sprintf(response, "%s.%d.%d.%d", cstr, ESP.getChipId(), response_i++, 1);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does not work because your function is a class method, but you could use [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to get the appropriate result:

```
ESP8266WiFiMesh mesh_node = ESP8266WiFiMesh(
    ESP.getChipId(),
    std::bind(&Mesh::manageRequest, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Comment: It actually solved the problem. Thank you a lot for help :)